# Mocking static method inside static method on powermock

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermock

I have a static method that looks for the current userSession object and returns a string.

```
public static String getCurrentUser()
    {
        UserSession userSession = buildUserSession();
        String responseString = userSession.getUsername();
        return responseString;
    }
```

For that, I call a private static method to instantiate the session object and return it to the first method. The buildUserSession method is reused on many other methods.

```
private static UserSession buildUserSession()
    {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
        String[] rolesArray = ConversionUtils.convertObjectArrayToStringArray(userDetails.getAuthorities().toArray());
        List<String> rolesList = Arrays.asList(rolesArray);
        UserSession userSession = new UserSession();
        userSession.setRoles(rolesList);
        userSession.setUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
        return userSession;
    }
```

From what I understand to this point, static method mocking is best made with mockito+powermock. Although, I am not managing to make this setup work when I have a static method inside a static method that I want to test. Can you help me with this unit test?

EDIT: I want to test getCurrentUser() and and mock buildUserSession().

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SecurityUtils.class)
public class SecurityUtilsTests {

    @Test
    public void getCurrentUserTest() throws Exception {
        // when
        String expected = "testUsername";
        UserSession userSession = new UserSession();
        userSession.setUsername(expected);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
        PowerMockito.when(SecurityUtils.class, "buildUserSession").thenReturn(userSession);
        String actual = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser();
        assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, you avoid static mocking like the plague. When you write your own code, then write easy to test code. When it is not testable without PowerMock(ito), then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I second that. If your test case relies on the outcome of a static method, this is a hint for poor design. A method should be only declared as *static* if it does not depend on the state of the program. A user session *does* change since principals, roles etc change. So why is your method declared as static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
public static String getCurrentUser()

private static UserSession buildUserSession()
```

And finally:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class);
```

You tell PowerMockito to mock **all** static methods within SecurityUtils. And then you want to *test* what happens when you call one of these methods?

Hint: the moment you go `mockStatic(SecurityUtils.class)` **all** static methods on that class are "erased".

Thus: you can't throw away all static methods on a class ... to then assume you can test one of them!

Beyond that: as soon as *static* gets into your way of doing unit testing, then turning to PowerMock(ito) is the **wrong** answer. Instead, you should rethink your design so that you can test it without PowerMock(ito).

In other words: learn how to write easy-to-test code. Then you don't need the big PowerMock(ito) hammer to work around the problems that hard-to-test code forces upon you.

Comment: Very helpful insight indeed. I have questioned my usage of static methods before. Although I figured it would be harder to test those statics, I kept those methods because they belong to a class that manages user session, and I would want that to be accessed without an annoying class instance. I had to make a choice between changing my architecture to be more test friendly, or trying to adapt the tests to it. I guess I will reconsider. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielPimenta You are very welcome. And just to be precise: albeit static is a bit of an abnormality in Java, it is still a legit language element. But it should be used with proper caution, and as said: as soon as it gets in your way ... dont use it, or use it in ways that dont affect your ability to unit test.

Comment: From what I know, it is not possible to test static methods with Mockito. So, whenever I write a static methods, I will be obliged to user PowerMockito. If using PowerMockito, as described by you, is a "not so good" practice, shouldnt I consider static methods a "not so good" practice altogether?

Comment: Careful. You can't **mock** static methods, unless you use PowerMock(ito) or JMockit. That doesn't mean you can't **test** them. Mocking is a *mean* that you sometimes have to resort to ... to write tests. So, be precise about the words you use ;-) ... you can write perfectly fine unit tests for static methods ... as long as those static methods can be called "as is" within your unit test setup!

Comment: I get it now. I am still a beginner at Java, but the discussion has been very useful to me thanks to you and @Panzerkroete.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to test `getCurrentUser()` and hereby mock `buildUserSession()`?

Instead of writing `PowerMockito.when(SecurityUtils.class, "buildUserSession").thenReturn(userSession);`

you should call

`PowerMockito.when(SecurityUtils.buildUserSession()).thenReturn(userSession);`

In the *when()*-clause you have to specify the mocked method as exactly as you would call it without mocking

Comment: the buildUserSession method is a private method. For that reason I used that when() clause notation.

Comment: If it is private, then use a *spy* on `SecurityUtils`instead of a *mock*.